# I'm trying to send multiple notification but it's not happenining

Tags: android, notifications

Here my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static int c=1;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notify(7,0,19);
        notify(7,0,20);
    }

    void notify(int date,int hour,int min)
    {
        int d=date,h=hour,mn=min;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }//end onCreate
}
```

Receiver Class code

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
                Toast.makeText(context, "helloooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("ALAARM", "yooooooooooo");
                Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
                context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

Next Service Class

```
public class NotificationService extends Service
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Notification no = new Notification.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_email)
                .setContentTitle("Mail from Sathya Tech")
                .setContentText("For more details   , Call Us on 040-65538958, 65538968, 65538978 or email to info@sathyatech.com")
                .build();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(1, no);

     /*   Notification no1 = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                .setContentTitle("Ravi")
                .setContentText("Hello Sir ")
                .build();

        NotificationManager nm1 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm1.notify(1212, no1);*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 nm.notify(1, no);
```

If you renotify with the same id, it updates the notification, overwriting the old one.  Use a different id for each unique notification

Comment: actually i'm calling two functions bt only later one is only being called